# атрибуты выделенного текста

Tags: delphi-7

доброго времени суток! подскажите, как можно в компоненте richedit применить атрибуты только для выделенного текста? т.е. текст, вводимый далее будет с прежними атрибутами

Comment: Вы, товарищ, о чем, собственно?  Текст, выделенный где? В браузере? В книге? В газете? В MS Word?

Comment: в компоненте RichEdit

Answer (score 1):

все, решил проблему. надо было сделать так:

> RichEdit1.SelStart :=
> RichEdit1.SelLength +
> RichEdit1.SelStart;
> RichEdit1.SelAtributes.Assign(RichEdit1.DefAtributes);

Answer (score 0):

хм..наверное, [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634855/how-to-change-selected-text-attribute-into-bold-in-tmemo-in-delphi-7) вы сможете найти что-то полезное:

а может быть еще и  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069889/delphi-trichedit-set-background-color-excluding-spaces)